# .NET MAUI: How to make RadioButton (with ControlTemplate) use all available space?

Tags: c#, xaml, radio-button, maui

I need to display a horizontal selection list where the items are spaced out evenly over the view.
For this purpose I would use a `FlexLayout` and populate its BindableLayout with the input data for selections.
However, **the `RadioButton` refuses to occupy the whole area** and setting the `WidthRequest` manually is not feasable, because the width of the view or the number of selectable options could vary.

Is there something I am missing?
Setting `VerticalOptions` to `Fill` at various elements has no effect.

In this picture, the black border shows that the `FlexLayout` works as expected and is only for display purposes:

[image: The current state]

Eventually, I would like to achieve the following effect, which is currently done in a hacky way using C# only:
[image: The desired effect]

The XAML code for the FlexLayout is as follows:

```
<FlexLayout Background="Gray"
            HeightRequest="100"
            JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly"
            AlignItems="Stretch">
<!-- Demo items for testing -->
<BindableLayout.ItemsSource>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
        <x:String>1</x:String>
        <x:String>2</x:String>
        <x:String>3</x:String>
    </x:Array>
</BindableLayout.ItemsSource>
<BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <!--Border to show that Flexlayout is behaving as expected-->
        <Border FlexLayout.Grow="1"
                Background="Transparent"
                Stroke="Black"
                StrokeThickness="2"
                StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10">
            <!--This should occupy all the space available--> 
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="Center" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                <RadioButton.ControlTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="Cyan">
                            <Border Background="Orange"
                                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10">
                            <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </RadioButton.ControlTemplate>
            </RadioButton>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
```

Edit: Because it was requested, this shows the "hacky way":
(`ContentGrid` is an empty `Grid` defined in XAML)

```
    internal void ReorderItems(IEnumerable<SelectionModel> items)
    {
        ContentGrid.Clear();
        ContentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            ContentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            Frame background = new()
            {
                HeightRequest = 44,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                CornerRadius = 8,
                BorderColor = Colors.Transparent,
                Padding = 0,
                Style = Resources["NormalStyle"] as Style
            };
            //Selected item is a bindable property on the control
            if (SelectedItem is not null && item.Number == SelectedItem.Number)
                background.Style = Resources["SelectedStyle"] as Style;

            TapGestureRecognizer tapRecognizer = new()
            {
                Command = SelectionChangedCommand,
                CommandParameter = item,
            };
            background.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapRecognizer);
            
            Label numberLabel = new()
            {
                Text = item.Number.ToString(),
                TextColor = Color.FromArgb("#6D6D6D"),
                FontSize = 14,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            };

            Image defaultImage = new()
            {
                Source = item.IsLocked ?
                    _lockImageSource : item.IsFinished ?
                    _finishedSource : item.IsStarted ?
                    _startedSource :
                    _notStartedSource,
                HeightRequest = 24,
                WidthRequest = 24,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            };

            HorizontalStackLayout centerLayout =
            [
                numberLabel, defaultImage
            ];
            centerLayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
            centerLayout.Spacing = 8;
            centerLayout.HeightRequest = 24;

            background.Content = centerLayout;

            ContentGrid.Add(background, counter, 0);

            counter++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the "hacky way" look like that you mention? What is that doing differently? Also, for a control to take all available space (based on the space that is provided by the parent), you should be using `Fill` instead of `Center` for the *HorizontalOptions*.

Comment: The hacky way does, for a pre-existing Grid:
- clear the grid
- loop through each item in the source
- adds a grid column
- fills it with new UI stuff created by C# (Label, Image, ...)

Comment: As for the HorizontalOptions: Fill has no effect, and anything other than center makes the radio button content move to the far left of its bounds

Comment: Instead of explaining the hacky way, please show it.

Comment: I updated the question with the "hacky way", thanks for reading through it!

Comment: May I ask what .NET version and what platform you are using?

Comment: I am using the latest .NET (8.0.2) and I am targeting Windows, Mac and iOS, all of which behave the same

Comment: Okay that's weird. It only works on Android for me.